# Combining multiple toggle scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am currently developing a javascript plugin for opening and closing multiple sections.  I have everything working fine but the script neets to be combined somehow so this can be scaled to more than 3 toggles.

For instance, if I have 20 different options I don't want to have to rewrite this script 20 times.

```
<div class="toggle1">Toggle 1</div>
<div class="toggle-close1">Close Toggle 1</div>

<div class="toggle2">Toggle 2</div>
<div class="toggle-close2">Close Toggle 2</div>

<div class="toggle3">Toggle 3</div>
<div class="toggle-close3">Close Toggle 3</div>


<div class="toggle-box1">Toggle 1 Box Information</div>
<div class="toggle-box2">Toggle 2 Box Information</div>
<div class="toggle-box3">Toggle 3 Box Information</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duBbE/

Comment: Classes need not be unique in the document. Problem solved?

Comment: I think we don't have the same definition of "plugin".

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you are storing your state data in the DOM. One approach would be to store an array of .toggle-box elements in your script instead.

Comment: If you used a Javascript looping structure to create all of those "Toggle Boxes", you could use the same structure to write the `.click()` handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rearrange your code to have toggleable elements in a wrapper, like so:

```
<div class='toggle-wrapper'>
  <a class='toggle-button'>Toggle</a>
  <div class='toggleable'>
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

You could do something like this:

```
$(".toggle-button").click(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".toggle-wrapper").find("> .toggleable").toggle();
});
```

Took the liberty of preparing a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/duBbE/1/

This is a rough idea but should help you get started

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do. If you are open to suggestions this can be done in a simple way.

HTML

```
<ul id="first">
  <li>Toggle 1</li>
  <li>Toggle 2</li>
  <li>Toggle 3</li>
  <li>Toggle 4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="second">
  <li>This is 1</li>
  <li>This is 2</li>
  <li>This is 3</li>
  <li>This is 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#second li{
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $("#first li").click(function(){
      var index = $(this).index();
      $("#second li:eq(" + index + ")").toggle();
   });
});
```

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/duBbE/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your HTML (just remove numbers in classename), you could end up with such a solution :

```
$(".toggle").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(".toggle-close").hide();
        $(".toggle").show();
        $(this).hide(0);
        $(".toggle-close").eq(index).show(0);
        $(".toggle-box").slideUp(800);
        $(".toggle-box").eq(index).slideToggle(800);
    });
});
$(".toggle-close").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(this).hide(0);
        $(".toggle").eq(index).show(0);
        $(".toggle-box").eq(index).slideToggle(800);
    });
});
```

**[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duBbE/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Eh.. not clear what you are really trying to do. Make a utility function (plugin?) to handle various hide/show methods? Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/duBbE/9/):

```
function toggleMe(options) {
  var _selector = !!options.sSelector ? options.sSelector : '.toggle'; // Pass any selector (can be #idSomething or .classSomething)
  var _method = !!options.sMethod ? options.sMethod : 'toggle'; // Pass in method let default be used ('toggle' will set it to other value of current state(show/hide))
  var _time = !!options.nTime ? options.nTime: 800; // Pass class in time to be used with certain methods
  //console.log(options);

  $(_selector).each(function(event){
    //console.log(this);
    try {
        if(_method == 'slideUp') {
            $(this).slideUp(_time);
        } else if(_method == 'slideToggle') {
            $(this).slideToggle(_time);
        } else if(_method == 'toggle') {
            this.style.display = this.style.display == 'none' ? 'block': 'none';
        } else if(_method == 'hide') {
            $(this).hide();
        }  else if(_method == 'show') {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            console.log('here in NADA Land');
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
  });
}; // End Function
```

Then initialize, bind or call it more generically. This should get you started, I think.

```
$(function() {

  toggleMe({sSelector: '.toggle3', sMethod: 'toggle'});
  toggleMe({sSelector: '.toggle-box3', sMethod: 'slideToggle'});
  toggleMe({sSelector: '.toggle-box2', sMethod: 'slideUp'});
  toggleMe({sSelector: '.toggle1', sMethod: 'hide'});
  $('.toggle-close1').on('click', function(event) {
      toggleMe({sSelector: '.toggle1', sMethod: 'toggle'});
      console.log(event.target.innerHTML.indexOf('Close'))
      event.target.innerHTML = $('.toggle1')[0].style.display == 'block'  ? 'Close Toggle 1': 'Open Toggle 1';
  });
});
```

You could swap the method if/else out for a case-switch, expand, add default case, etc.